# How to change font properties of chart axes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

How do I change the font properties of chart axes in Excel 2007 & 2010?

NOT the axis *title*; that one's easy. I'm asking about the font of the axis itelf.

It records equivalent to this in Excel 2010:

```
shEditSizeScales.ChartObjects("MyChart").Chart.Axes(xlCategory).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size=12
```

But I get an error on that, and I don't see anything past TextFrame2 in the Watch pane.

Even if I step through the recorded code, it gives me the same error.

I've looked through the object model and I don't see it.

How is it done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font
        '.Bold = msoTrue
        .Size = 18
End With
```

Source: [MS Ref link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/format-axis-font-in-vba/2fe979b0-1daa-415d-a550-c9e2c9d29fab)