# Excel Secondary Axis font colour change by VBA without activating chart

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028681/how-to-change-font-properties-of-chart-axes) on font properties and it's got me part of the way.

I'm trying to change the font colour. I so far have the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).TickLabels.Font.Color = 5855577
```

This works fine.

What's irritating me is that I have to do this via activating the chart.
Surely there's a better way. If I do either of the following it doesn't work:

```
Dim cht As ChartObject
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2")
cht.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).TickLabels.Font.Color = 5855577

'-------------------------

Dim cht As ChartObject, ax As Axes
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2")
Set ax = cht.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)
ax.TickLabels.Font.Color = 5855577
```

I generally try to avoid selecting or activating in my code so this is just annoying! Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Axes` isn't actually a member of a `ChartObject`, but a member of `ChartObject.Chart`.

Therefore, you want to access the `Axes`-collection of `ChartObject.Chart`

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).TickLabels.Font.Color = vbRed
End with
```

Why does it work if you activate it first? Well, because `ActiveChart` actually returns the `Chart`-object, instead of the `ChartObject`-object.

Comment: Thanks Martin, great explanation also.

Comment: Glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're trying to record a macro, the code for filling the text forecolor won't (TextFrame2 object) work due to a bug already reported to Microsoft, so using the code below, you can do it without issue. You can also change the properties according to your needs.

Use this code:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
```

Comment: Would be nice to add more details than just the code

Comment: Thank you Tukan for your comment. I just edit my answer :)

Comment: Great! Much better now.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer also to avoid working with `ActvieSheet` (if possible).

The code below, will set the nested properties under `ChartObject` for the properties you need, such as `Chart.Axes` , and later also for `TickLabels`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Chart_AutoSetup()

Dim ChtObj As ChartObject, ax As Axis, T2 As TickLabels
Dim ShtCht  As Worksheet

' change "Chart_Sheet" to your sheet's name (where you have your chart's data)
Set ShtCht = Worksheets("Chart_Sheet") ' <-- set the chart's location worksheet

Set ChtObj = ShtCht.ChartObjects("Chart2") '<-- set chart object

With ChtObj      
    Set ax = .Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary) '<-- set chart axes to secondary
    Set T2 = ax.TickLabels  '<-- set Ticklables object

    T2.Font.Color = 5855577
    T2.Font.Italic = True ' <-- just another property you can easily modify
End With

End Sub
```